# Dynamically create an entity instance and add a new entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Please, consider the following example:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var auditableEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries<ISomething>())
    {
        if (auditableEntity.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            //Create a new instance of the same entity type. 
            //I don't know which one will be. They just have the same interface.
            var newEntity = ?; //???Reflection???

            //ISomething known properties.
            newEntity.propX = "1";
            newEntity.propY = "2";

            //Invoke Add method.
            ??.Add(newEntity); 
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

I need to **dynamically create an instance** of all my ISomething entities during `SaveChanges()` method in order to **add a new particular entry** on it.

Any help will be very welcome.

Regards

Comment: You'll at *least* need a concrete type to create. You can't just use `ISomething`, as the concrete type could be *anything*. Once you've got access to the type, use `[Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx)` and cast the result to `ISomething`.

Comment: @Rob all ISomething will be an entity but I don't know which one because many implements this same interface.

Comment: How will EF know which table to insert the row into?

Comment: @Rob for a better understanding please consider `foreach` as `ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added)` instead. ChangeTracker brings the current entity in item.Entity.GetType().Name for example.

Comment: In that case, you'd use `auditableEntity.Entity.GetType()` and construct a new object via `Activator.CreateInstance()` (then cast that result back to `ISomething`).

Comment: @Rob How may I be able to call `Add()` by using `Activator.CreateInstance()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the non generic [`DbContext.Set Method (Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.103).aspx) to get the corresponding non generic [`DbSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.103).aspx). Then you can use [`Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504(v=vs.103).aspx) method to create a new instance of the same type and [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679354(v=vs.103).aspx) method to add it.

Something like this:

```
var entityType = auditableEntity.Entity.GetType();
var dbSet = Set(entityType);
var newEntity = (ISomething)dbSet.Create();

//ISomething known properties.
newEntity.propX = "1";
newEntity.propY = "2";

dbSet.Add(newEntity);
```

Comment: This non generic method is extremely useful.

Comment: your sample apparently works perfect but SaveChanges() method is ignoring the new ones entities created.

Comment: There is nothing special in the way the sample works, hence no reason added entities to be ignored. Btw, they should appear immediately in the same `ChangeTracker` used in your sample, so I would add `ToList` to buffer the list of the entries I'm supposed to iterate. Anyway, if the entities are ignored, there must be some code causing that. You can create a new question and provide a reproducible example.

Comment: In fact, I was cloning new entities like `newEntity = existentEntity` before to add them and all additions were being considered the same. My fault